# Destroy Dependent for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have three models.

```
class Book
  has_many :book_checkouts, dependent: :destroy
end

class BookCheckout
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user
end

class User
  has_many :books
  has_many :book_checkouts
end
```

If I DESTROY a BOOK, I want the BOOK_CHECKOUT associated with any model destroyed. But that doesn't work. I have no nested routes either.

```
routes

  resources :users
  resources :book_checkouts
  resources :books
```

I am not exactly sure what are the requirements for dependent DESTROY to work. I think the problem resides that BookCheckout belongs to two classes?

Comment: Please show the code where you actually destroy the record.

Comment: Do you mean the method in the controller or where I have been calling it. I am calling the method within the rails console.

Comment: So, you are just callling `book.destroy`?  The associations you've posted are configured correctly, so you could have a callback or something else causing the problem.

Comment: Oh you were right, my associations were right and calling Book.destroy WITHIN CONSOLE skipped deleting the association.

Comment: @goda actually they should still work fine even in the console..